# How to store (in a variable) the Firestore document data that was read from database in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to read data from Firebase Firestore, but there is no way to store the document data in a variable, because those variables will just be local and will be "garbage collected"

I tried making a function that tries to return the document content, but that resulted in an error because the "getDocument" method does not allow a return type.

```
docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
        var dataValues = document.data()!.values
        self.textInput = dataDescription
        //I first tried doing it without the word self, but it gave an error insisting that I add self, but adding it makes it a local variable and not the String variable defined in the class
        //textInput is a String
        print("Document data: \(document.data()!.values)")
        //This will print out everything in the document
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}
```

I am trying to see if I can set any variable to the document data and still be able to access the data after reading the database.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to take look to https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions , Firebase have one of the most complete documentation, this will help you, to be exact you should do it like this:

```
let sfReference = db.collection("cities").document("SF")

db.runTransaction({ (transaction, errorPointer) -> Any? in
    let sfDocument: DocumentSnapshot
    do {
        try sfDocument = transaction.getDocument(sfReference)
    } catch let fetchError as NSError {
        errorPointer?.pointee = fetchError
        return nil
    }

    guard let oldPopulation = sfDocument.data()?["population"] as? Int else {
        let error = NSError(
            domain: "AppErrorDomain",
            code: -1,
            userInfo: [
                NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Unable to retrieve population from snapshot \(sfDocument)"
            ]
        )
        errorPointer?.pointee = error
        return nil
    }

    // Note: this could be done without a transaction
    //       by updating the population using FieldValue.increment()
    transaction.updateData(["population": oldPopulation + 1], forDocument: sfReference)
    return nil
}) { (object, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("Transaction failed: \(error)")
    } else {
        print("Transaction successfully committed!")
    }
}
```

as described in the Firebase Documentation.

Comment: I know about transactions, but I am trying to assign a variable to the data that I just read. Whenever I try to assign a variable to the data read from the database, it gives an error and insists on adding the keyword "self", which will create a new variable and will be "garbage collected" after reading the database is done. In case my wording was bad, my question is: Is there any way to assign a variable to the data that I read from the Firebase Firestore

Comment: Onestly I don't know swift very well but,  when I download the document I do doc.getDocument().toObject(nameClass.class) and obtain a variable with the data(the class should have the same structure of the document) and then I upload directly the variable with .set(variable), knowing that, you can store the data from the document in a variable(with the same structure) and assign the other variable to that and than upload, I think, hope this will help.